# Sequence of declaring a model variable in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, fatal-error

I am a beginner of Zend Framework2. Following the example of "Zend Framework 2.0 by Example Beginner's Guide" I got stuck in a weird problem.

Here is my project structure.

[image: project structure]

I have a simple function `creatureUser()` in `RegisterController.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
use Users\Form\RegisterFilter;
use users\Model\User;
use Users\Model\UserTable;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //$form = new RegisterForm();
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegisterForm');
        $viewModel  = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form)); 
        return $viewModel; 
    }

    public function confirmAction()
    {
        $viewModel  = new ViewModel(); 
        return $viewModel; 
    }

    public function processAction()
    {
        if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
                    'controller' => 'register', 
                    'action' =>  'index' 
                ));
        }

        $post = $this->request->getPost();

        //$form = new RegisterForm();
        //$inputFilter = new RegisterFilter();
        //$form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegisterForm');

        $form->setData($post);
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $model = new ViewModel(array(
                'error' => true,
                'form'  => $form,
            ));
            $model->setTemplate('users/register/index');
            return $model;
        }

        // Create user
        $this->createUser($form->getData());

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
            'controller' => 'register', 
            'action' =>  'confirm' 
        ));
    }

    protected function createUser(array $data)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
        $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

        //$user = new User();
        $user->exchangeArray($data);
        $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);

        $userTable->saveUser($user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When run the above code I get an error:

> Fatal error: *Class 'users\Model\User' not found in C:\WebApp\ZF2Skeleton\module\Users\src\Users\Controller\RegisterController.php on line 90.*

But If I move `$user = new User();` below. Like this one:

```
protected function createUser(array $data)
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
    $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

    $user = new User();
    $user->exchangeArray($data);
    $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);

    $userTable->saveUser($user);
    return true;
}
```

It will work perfectly. Can anyone tell me how this happens, please? Is it a sequence problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple typo in your controller:

```
use users\Model\User;
```

should be:

```
use Users\Model\User;
```

(note the capital 'U' in 'Users').

Comment: Thank you Ruben. It works. But now I am confused that why it works after I put  $user = new User(); down below after declaring $tableGateway although I keep `use users\Model\User;` ( in lower 'u') this mistake.

Comment: @Zhigang Not quite sure, but my guess is that it has something to do with this line: $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User); being executed first.